# Cat files in Hadoop that do not end with gz

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, sh

I am trying to cat files that are not gz

```
hdfs dfs -cat /*.gz
```

How do I cat all files that do not end with .gz?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. If you'd like to clarify your question, you should edit the original.

Comment: Hadoop does not provide all these operations hence can't use the same things as bash.

Comment: There's no answers on your original question, so you're free to edit it to clarify your intended scope. That exactly what the comments on the original question are trying to clarify. In particular, you should elaborate on "Hadoop does not provide all these operations".

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will do that.